# Hex spell and multiple attacks

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does the extra d6 damage apply to *all* attacks against the hexed creature (for example, Scorching Ray or Magic Missile) or just one?

Comment: Just a note that a magic missile is not an attack, so hex doesn't stack with it (see the answers in the duplicate question)

Comment: I read the related question. It sheds some light, but it seems strange that a Magic Missile is not an attack and Scorching ray is. In any case it is a IMHO excessive damage multiplier.

Comment: See [What Counts as an Attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71245/what-counts-as-an-attack) for clarification around why _magic missile_ isn't an attack. Hex is equivalent in power to the ranger's _hunter's mark_ spell.

Comment: @piffy because you don't roll ad d20 to see if you hit or don't.  That's why MM isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All Attacks Gain an Extra 1d6**

> **Hex**
>
> ... Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to the
>   target **whenever you hit it with an attack**.

Comment: Magic Missle isn't an attack .