# If the Dragon's Breath spell is cast on a familiar, does it use the wizard's DC or familiar's DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, saving-throw, difficulty-class

XGE has a spell that lets anything that breaths spew magical energy from its mouth for 10 rounds called [Dragon's Breath](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dragons-breath) (p. 154). Part of it reads:

> Each creature in that area must make a Dexterity saving throw, taking 3d6 damage of the chosen type on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

It's been established that you can put it on your familiar, per [Can a familiar from the Find Familiar spell use Dragon's Breath?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110157/can-a-familiar-from-the-find-familiar-spell-use-dragons-breath)

Do you use your own spell save DC or your familiar's? What would a familiar's spell save DC be? Seems like if it's a Dexterity save, it should be coming from the source of the fire.

Comment: Really this question generalizes to *any* creature other than yourself you might cast it on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## It is the spellcaster's spell save DC

> The DC to resist one of *your spells* equals 8 + *your* spellcasting ability modifier + *your* proficiency bonus + any special modifiers. ([PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) - Saving Throws)

So the person that casts the spell sets the DC (as indicated by the term "you"/"your" which the PHB uses throughout this section to refer exclusively to the caster).

And regardless of the familiar delivering the spell, the PC is the one who cast it.