# Does splash damage trigger the bonus damage from the Hex spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Will a *hexed* creature that is affected by splash damage (e.g. the *green-flame blade* spell from the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*) take *hex* damage as well?

Comment: Yes...green flame blade...it was question about a hex blade build for a warlock...  sorry about newbie errors on questions...

Comment: @RubenLopez No trouble! Just a bit of delay, to make sure that answer-writers are on the exact same page as you are, to ensure the answers are fully on-subject. The hold on answers is released. :)

Answer (score 5):

"Splash damage" doesn't have any special definition in D&D 5e, so I assume you're using it to refer to ["damage taken by players or objects in the area surrounding a point of [...] impact"](https://www.giantbomb.com/splash-damage/3015-347/).

## *Hex* only does damage when you hit the target with an attack.

From the description of the *[hex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex)* spell:

> Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to the target **whenever you hit it with an attack**.

## *Green-flame blade*'s additional damage is not an attack.

See the spell description of *[green-flame blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade)* (SCAG p. 143):

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell’s range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack’s normal effects, and **green fire leaps from the target to a different creature of your choice that you can see within 5 feet of it. The second creature takes fire damage equal to your spellcasting ability modifier.**

The original melee weapon attack against the first creature specified by *green-flame blade* is, of course, an attack. However, the additional damage that the spell deals to a different creature within 5 feet is simply automatically dealt; there is no attack that can hit or miss.

[Jeremy Crawford clarifies the meanings of "hit" and "miss" here on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/949111167582060544):

> A hit is when you make an attack roll and succeed. A miss is when you make an attack roll and fail.

The only things that are attacks are things with attack rolls, or things that are specifically stated as such (e.g. a shove or a grapple is described as a "special melee attack"). For more details, see this question: [What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71245/what-counts-as-an-attack)

As such, the "splash damage" of green-flame blade in particular does not meet the necessary condition for the extra damage from *hex*. For other causes of "splash damage", it depends on whether an attack roll is being made (and whether that attack roll hits, of course).