# Do melee spell attacks with a range of touch bypass armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, touch-attacks, attack-roll

Short version: Do melee spell attacks take into account armor when the range is **Touch**?

---

Longer version: Assuming a prepare an [Inflict Wounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/inflict-wounds) (PHB253) spell, that has the following properties:

- Range: Touch
- Description: Make a melee spell attack against a creature you can reach. On a hit [..]

Assuming that the opponent that I choose as a target has a total 15AC:

- 10 Base
- 3 Armor (possibly natural armor)
- 2 Dexterity

What should my attack roll be to successfully hit? 15 (the whole above) or 12 (since just touching, armor offers no protection)?

Comment: Was about to add an answer, but this does indeed look like a duplicate. You may be thinking of earlier editions which included the concept of a "Touch AC", but see duplicate question for 5th edition answer.

Comment: Did not even remember the name "Touch AC", thought it was a given. This however pretty much sums it up, on to homebrewing the rule back in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's 15, the whole above

In 5e, armor might protect you from spells. Armor Class (AC) protects you from all attacks, as the PHB says:

> **Armor Class (AC).** Armor protects its wearer from attacks.

Also, Jeremy Crawford, the lead game designer, explicitly said that so-called "melee spell attacks" [were stoppable by armor](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/674405075024932864).

Keep in mind that "attack" is a game term. For more details, see [What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71245/what-counts-as-an-attack)