# Does the Green Flame-Blade cantrip work with the Zephyr Strike spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, actions, cantrips

Does the Green-Flame Blade cantrip work with the Zephyr Strike spell?

Specifically, I am unsure as to whether the [Zephyr Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/zephyr-strike) spell (XGtE, p. 171) requires you take the Attack action. Its description states:

> Once before the spell ends, you can give yourself advantage on one weapon attack roll on your turn.

I'm unsure whether the making of this attack would fall under the Attack action, or if it could work in conjunction with Green-Flame Blade.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Yes, because *zephyr strike* does not require the Attack action.

The [Attack action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Attack) is one type of action you can use in combat. There are other ways to make weapon attack rolls. For further explanation, see these related questions:

- [What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781)
- [What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71245)

The cantrip [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) is one such example of making a weapon attack roll without the Attack action. Its description says:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell’s range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack’s normal effects...

[*Zephyr strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/zephyr-strike) does not mention the Attack action, but instead refers to:

> one weapon attack roll on your turn

If you cast *green-flame blade* on your turn, and use it to make a melee weapon attack roll, then you are making a weapon attack roll on your turn. Thus it could work with *zephyr strike*.

Comment: Isn't there a difference between "weapon attack" and "attack with a weapon"? _Zephyr strike_ says: "Once before the spell ends, you can give yourself advantage on one **weapon attack roll** on your turn." but _green-flame blade_ says: "As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee **attack with a weapon** against one creature..." - I can't find a related Q&A about this, else I would have included a link, but I think there is known to be a difference between the two...

Comment: @NathanS https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/09/06/what-specifically-does-melee-weapon-attack-mean/ 
By this and the additions below, a 'weapon attack' is an 'attack with a weapon', except that unarmed strike can be used for a melee weapon attack (melee attack with a weapon)

Comment: Fair enough, I'm convinced; I must have misremembered about those two terms having some significant difference in 5e. In that case, since that was the only reason I hesitated to upvote, have a +1.