# Can the Hexblade warlock's Armor of Hexes feature be used to cancel a ranged spell attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, warlock, attack

Can Armor of Hexes be used to cancel a ranged spell attack like *scorching ray*? Does one ray count as an attack roll because you roll to hit?

The [Hexblade warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheHexblade)'s [Armor of Hexes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ArmorofHexes-759) feature says (XGtE, p. 56):

> At 10th level, your hex grows more powerful. If the target cursed by your Hexblade’s Curse hits you with an **attack roll**, you can use your reaction to roll a d6. On a 4 or higher, the attack instead misses you, regardless of its roll.

The [*scorching ray*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scorching-ray) spell description says:

> You create three rays of fire and hurl them at targets within range. You can hurl them at one target or several. Make a **ranged spell attack** for each ray. On a hit, the target takes 2d6 fire damage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Armor of Hexes can stop any attack roll

Any attack (little a) that requires an attack roll can be stopped by Armor of Hexes. See [What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71245/48759) for more details on what counts as an attack for this purpose. The short version is; anything that requires an attack roll is considered an attack.

Armor of Hexes only requires that you are hit by something requiring an attack roll. So if your target is rolling to hit you, the ability works. If you are making a saving throw, it doesn't.

*Scorching Ray* requires separate attack rolls, therefore Armor of Hexes can only potentially block 1 ray as you only have one reaction.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes it would

Quoting the description, it says:

> ...hits you with an attack roll...

Since they would have to roll to hit you to make a ranged spell attack, you could potentially negate the attack with your Armor of Hexes ability.