# Does the Vital Sacrifice feat cause Fireball or Magic Missile to deal additional damage? If so, to whom?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting, saving-throw

The Vital Sacrifice feat from *Tal’dorei Campaign Setting: Reborn* says you can expend a blood boon to gain the following benefit:

> When you hit with an attack or spell, you deal an additional 2d6 necrotic damage.

*Fireball* and *Magic Missile* clearly do not involve attacks, so **this is not a duplicate of questions asking what it means to hit with an attack**.

But *Fireball* and *Magic Missile* are spells. Does damaging a creature with a non-attack spell such as *Fireball* count as a "hit with a spell"? What about damaging a creature with a non-attack spell that uses the word "hit" in its spell description, such as *Magic Missile*?

**This is not a duplicate of questions asking if one can hit with an attack without an attack roll**, because this question is about "hit with a spell", *not* "hit with an attack."

Does dealing damage with a spell such as *Fireball* count as a "hit with a spell" for the purposes of this feat, thus dealing additional 2d6 necrotic damage? What about *Magic Missile*, where the word "hit" is used explicitly, even without an attack roll? If so, does it deal the additional 2d6 necrotic damage to *every* creature that took damage from the spell, or only the ones that did not make their saving throw, or only one creature of your choice?

Comment: Also related: [What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71245/28941)

Comment: Both of those cover "hit with an attack" but not "hit with a spell"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The rules or spell tell you when a spell "hits"

The PHB rules for spellcasting (p. 205) say:

> Some spells require the caster to make an attack roll
> to determine whether the spell effect **hits** the intended
> target

That is, to hit with such a spell, you make an attack roll. This language is different from the one for spells that require a saving throw, which says

> Many spells specify that a target can make a saving
> throw to avoid some or all of a spell’s effects. The spell
> specifies the ability that the target uses for the save and
> what happens on a success or failure.

Success or failure for spells that ask for saving throws, like *fireball*'s area effect, do not use the "hit" language. Neither does *fireball* itself.

The Tal'Dorei feature however is not just written confusingly, because there are spells that can hit without requiring an attack roll. For example *[magic missile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-missile)* says

> You create three glowing darts of magical force. Each dart **hits** a creature of your choice that you can see within range.

There is no attack roll involved here. So this feature would work with *magic missile*, because it says it hits, or with a spell attack, but not with *fireball*, which does not say it hits.

Comment: In order to prevent this question being marked as a duplicate, I had to add details about _Magic Missile_ into the question's title and body. Unfortunately that makes the blanket "no" at the top of this a bit awkward. For future readers' context, the question initially only mentioned _Fireball_ by name, and the **No** is about _Fireball_.

Comment: @Kerrick No problem, I took off the "No"

Comment: I doubt that "hit" is a 5e game term. From all readings it is used in it's normal english meaning, in which case a Fireball also hits when the save fails. DnD is not a grammar competition but a game using regular language a lot.