# Does the Quick Toss maneuver work with a Magic Stone?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, combat-maneuver

The Quick Toss maneuver from Tashas Cauldron indicates a ranged attack can be made with a bonus action for expending a superiority die.

Could you quickly toss a Magic Stone?  How much damage would it do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### This does not work

Quick Toss states (emphasis mine):

> As a bonus action, you can expend one superiority die and make a ranged attack **with a weapon that has the thrown property.** [...]

The [*magic stone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-stone) cantrip states:

> [...] You or someone else can make a ranged spell attack with one of the pebbles by throwing it or hurling it with a sling. If thrown, it has a range of 60 feet. [...]

The attacks from *magic stone* are spell attacks<sup>1</sup> and so do not use a weapon, and the stones also do not have the actual thrown property.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Note that when using a Sling, though you are not making a weapon attack and are instead making a spell attack, you *are* making an attack that *uses* a weapon. However, the Sling does not have the thrown property, so this doesn't work either.

Comment: Reluctantly agree.  I *want* this to work, and your DM could allow it, but *technically* a magic stone isn't a weapon, thrown or otherwise.

Comment: IMHO a DM should absolutely allow it. You're using an otherwise rather niche feat and niche cantrip (two rather high opportunity costs), only to get an extra attack in your second round [1st round cast magic stone w/ bonus action, 2nd round throw it with bonus action]. However, RAW it doesnt, talk to your DM

Comment: > _The attacks from magic stone are spell attacks and so do not use a weapon_
Not entirely correct - you can use a magic stone with a sling to make a "ranged (spell) attack with a weapon". See: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80254
Of course sling doesn't have thrown property either, so it doesn't change the conclusion.