# Does the Ranger's Favoured Foe Ability from Tasha's work with Cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, cantrips

I have an idea for a wisdom based Horizon Walker.  I was thinking of taking *shillelagh* and *produce flame* from the Druidic Warrior fighting style. Produce flame is purely so that I at least have *one* ranged option when it is necessary,  but I would primarily be a melee fighter.  I know that *hunter's mark* works with only weapon attacks but I noticed that the description of favoured foe only states "when you hit with an attack roll", not with a "weapon attack."

Would produce flame be able to benefit from, and apply the damage from, Favoured Foe?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related: "[Is a spell with an attack roll “an attack” for the purpose of Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33923)" and "[What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71245)"

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 33):

#### Favored Foe works with any cantrip that uses an attack roll.

[Favored Foe](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/ranger#FavoredFoe) says:

> When you hit a creature **with an attack roll**, you can call on your mystical bond with nature to mark the target as your favored enemy for 1 minute or until you lose your concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell).

[*Produce Flame*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/produce-flame) says:

> Make a ranged spell attack.

If it hits, you can use Favored Foe. It doesn't specify melee or ranged, weapon or spell. It works with *any* attack roll.

Note, *it doesn't work with cantrips that use saving throws*, such as *sacred flame*.

Comment: Also of note: it effects any spell roll, not just cantrips.