# Can a rogue use the Steady Aim optional class feature with attack spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, attack, rogue

Can a rogue use the [Steady Aim](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/rogue#SteadyAim) optional class feature (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, p. 62) with attack spells?

Steady Aim Lv3 Rogue optional ability states you take a bonus act to gain advantage on the next attack roll you make.

I have a Rogue Warlock that has Eldritch Blast cantrip. Can he then use Steady Aim with his first Eldritch Blast?

I know EB is a RSA, yet the ability specifically states "advantage on the next attack roll". So does it work with spells that requires an attack roll?

Comment: Have you read the feature? Could you give more details about what is confusing you? What part of Steady Aim is confusing to you? More details is usually good around here.

Comment: At least related: "[Does the Ranger's Favoured Foe Ability from Tasha's work with Cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180666)" and "[Is a spell with an attack roll “an attack” for the purpose of Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33923)" and "[What counts as an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71245)"

Comment: You can even use it with a spell that doesn't require an attack roll, or you can use Steady Aim as a bonus action and then take the dash action. It will just be a complete waist. But nothing in Steady Aim restricts the rest of your turn besides movement speed.

Comment: Good question! I was curious about the same, thematically its a bit unexpected for the Rogue's aim to help casters, but this is quite useful for the Arcane Trickster.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Yes.

*Steady Aim* states:

> As a bonus action, you give yourself advantage on your next **attack roll** on the current turn...

Anything requiring an attack roll is an attack as stated on page 194 of the PHB:

> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: **if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack.**

This includes spells that require an attack roll and there's nothing in Steady Aim's description to exclude spell attacks. If the spell *doesn't* require an attack roll though then the answer is no, you can't use Steady Aim with that spell.